# Extracting CSV from iSeries SAV file

Tags: csv, ibm-midrange

I have received a CSV that has been converted/compressed/compacted into a SAV file from iSeries. Is there a way to extract the CSV file out of the SAV file using any utilities, or do I need an iSeries setup to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SAVF` is a proprietary, relatively undocumented IBM file format.  By far the easiest solution will be to use the native utilities to extract it.

Many midrange shops don't realize there is a ZIP utility integrated into the system.  The Java [`jar`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzjar.htm) utility can create and extract standard ZIP files.

It does not take much effort to copy a physical file (table) to the IFS (stream file system) in ASCII CSV format and zip it:

```
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(LIB/FILE) TOSTMF('path/file.csv') STMFCODPAG(*STDASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF)
QSH CMD('jar cvfM path/file.zip -C path file.csv')
```

Comment: Alternatively, some shops have PGP on IBM i (formerly aka iSeries), which would encrypt the file and compress it at the same time.  This could be a good solution if data security might be any concern.